# Oculus DK2 won't display Unity 5

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

I am having a problem with my game showing on my Oculus. I checked mark "Virtual Reality Supported" in Player settings. When I run the exe, I right click to use the option to play on Rift, but it just plays on my Desktop(and it plays fine on its own). The Oculus Configurations Utility shows that my Oculus is "ready," but it doesn't detect to run on the Oculus. I haven't used my Oculus in awhile and use to having the direct to rift option and extended mode, so it's pretty foreign to me- so help is appreciated.

Comment: Which exact version of Unity are you using? Which Oculus runtime are you using? E.g. Unity 5.3, the changelog (https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.3) mentions "VR: Oculus 0.8 Runtime required for Windows."

Comment: Note that the *focused* application - if it supports VR - is what will get displayed in the HMD. So, if working in the editor, you'll need the game view visible (not scene view) and Unity will need to be the active / focused application. Are you using the Oculus or OpenVR plugin?